# Подскажите как скорректировать большой набор текстовых данных согласно примерам для поиска дубликатов в списке элементов?

Tags: машинное-обучение, big-data, data-mining, ml.net

У меня есть большой список названий товаров. Большая часть текста нуждается в корректировке. Я не очень знаком с нейронными сетями и пакетной обработкой данных. Мне посоветовали посмотреть в сторону библиотеки ML.Net.
Допустим, я смогу сделать небольшой набор данных, для обучения нейронки, которые откорректировы так, как мне хотелось бы их видеть, и выгрузить результат в формате CSV.

Где:
1 колонка - оригинальное название,
2 колонка - скорректированное название,
остальные колонки - это какие-то дополнительные данные, которые мне пригодятся.

Данные - это набор наименований товаров в нашей БД. Но данные вбивались очень неаккуратно и очень много дублей (которые просто по-разному вбиты). В некоторых данных содержатся характеристики товаров, которые нужно бы вообще убрать из названия и переместить в отлельные поля. В итоге, дубли позиций можно будет определить, когда скорректируются данные.
Вот пример класса, в который серилизуется CSV:

```
class ProductData
{
    [LoadColumn(0)]
    public string OriginalName;

    [LoadColumn(1)]
    public string CorrectedName;

    [LoadColumn(2)]
    public string Size;

    [LoadColumn(3)]
    public string Color;

    [LoadColumn(4)]
    public string Type;

    [LoadColumn(5)]
    public string Manufacturer;

    [LoadColumn(6)]
    public string Model;

    [LoadColumn(7)]
    public string Modification;

    [LoadColumn(8)]
    public string SpecificCount;

    [LoadColumn(9)]
    public string SKU;
}
```

CSV я могу подготовить так:

```
JB Food Bags Small;JB Food Bags;Small;;Bags;JB Food;;;;
JB Food Bags Large;JB Food Bags;Large;;Bags;JB Food;;;;
PELELAC POLYURETHANE VARNISH MATT;PELELAC POLYURETHANE VARNISH ;;MATT;VARNISH;PELELAC;;;;
PELELAC POLYURETHANE VARNISH GLOSS;PELELAC POLYURETHANE VARNISH ;;GLOSS;VARNISH;PELELAC;;;;
Stanley Bits PZ 1,2,3 - -;Stanley Bits PZ 1,2,3;;;Bits;Stanley;;;;
Baseus USB/TYPE-C 40W Blue;Baseus USB/TYPE-C 40W;;Blue;;Baseus;;;;
Stylus for tablet iPad APPLE Pencil 1st generation MQLY3 white;Stylus for tablet iPad APPLE Pencil 1st generation MQLY3;;White;Stylus;Apple;Pencil 1st generation;;;
```

Я не особо знаю, как обучать такие сети данными и способны ли они на такие корректировки, после обучения на готовых данных. Поэтому прошу здесь совета как это лучше сделать или может обратить внимание на какие-то готовые библиотеки или сети, которые помогу мне с решением данной задачи.
Заранее спасибо.